# Are all the current badges sufficient for our community?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, badges

Are all the current badges sufficient for the community or are there badges that don't fit the community?

Related:

- [Is the Tumbleweed badge working?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329/is-the-tumbleweed-badge-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of badges is expanding and any new badge will be rolled out network wide.

Comment: Well, the question is somewhat misunderstood now but actually does no longer apply. I was asking if there was any individual badge that did not apply to THIS community because of its nature, but as we're two years further I guess that has already ironed out over time. The tags are just fine, I guess...