# Is the Tumbleweed badge working?

Tags: support, status-completed, badges

I wounder if the Tumbleweed badge is working here on Programmers.

I had a question with low views, no comments and no answer in 12 days, and I didn't get a Tubmleweed.

Is it working or is the requirements very hard? Maybe it's inactivated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues at play:

1. [The text for the Tumbleweed badge on Programmers.SE is out of date](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/tumbleweed-text-on-programmers-se-is-out-of-date). It should read:

   > Asked a question with no votes, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week
2. None of your questions meet the requirements for the badge, given the correct definition. If you're curious about the viewcount requirement, it's [10-15](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32376/tumbleweed-how-many-views-is-low).

Comment: +1 Based myself on an outdated Meta.SO topic, should visit that site more...

Comment: +1 - well researched, that man!